# What are the correct functional programming terms for what I'm doing here?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I recently needed a function to deep clone an object. I started with the code given as an accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/1253156

However, our SonarQube complained that the function was too complex, because of the multiple if statements. So I refactored the code to this:

```
function getContainer(input) {
    return input.isContainer ? input : {
        isContainer: true,
        isDone: false,
        value: input
    };
}

function processor(isApplicable, process) {
    return input => {
        const container = getContainer(input);
        const { isDone, value } = container;
        if (isDone) {
            return container;
        }
        if (isApplicable(value)) {
            return Object.assign({}, container, {
              value: process(value),
              isDone: true
            });
        }
        return container;
    };
}

const processNoObject = processor(isNoObject, cloneNoObject);
const processDate = processor(isDate, cloneDate);
const processMap = processor(isMap, cloneMap);
const processArray = processor(isArray, cloneArray);
const processObject = processor(isObject, cloneObject);

function clone(input) {
    const { isDone, value } = processNoObject(processDate(processMap(processArray(processObject(input)))));
    if (isDone) {
        return value;
    }
    throw new Error('Unable to copy object! Its type isn\'t supported');
}
```

I left out the functions isObject, cloneObject, etc. here for brevity's sake. The full working code can be found here: http://codepen.io/pahund/pen/KWwjWp/

What are the correct FP terms for what I called "processor" and "container" in my code? I'm assuming processor is something like a monad, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not monads, because you haven't specified a set of operations (“unit”, “flatMap”) that satisfy the monad laws. However, your design is clearly inspired by monads, with a function that wraps a value in some container and a function that lifts other functions from the value-level to the container-level.

For a monad, we need a constructor `(value) -> Container` and a flatMap operation `(Container, (value) -> Container) -> Container`. Your container has two possible cases (isDone and not isDone). This could be implemented as:

```
function Container(value) {  // this is the constructor
  return {
    value: value,
    isDone: false,
    flatMap: function flatMap (f) { return f(value) },
  };
}

function ContainerIsDone(value) {
  return {
    value: value,
    isDone: true,
    flatMap: function flatMap (f) { return this },
  };
}
```

For convenience, `flatMap` has been made a method here instead of a free function.

If this satisfies the monad laws (and it does), then:

- it has left identity: `Container(x).flatMap(f) === f(x)` for all values `x` and for all suitable functions `f`.
- it has right identity: `c.flatMap(Container) === c` for all containers `c`.
- it is associative: `c.flatMap(f).flatMap(g) === c.flatMap(x => f(x).flatMap(g))` for all containers `c` and suitable functions `f, g`.

Your `processor` could now be expressed as:

```
function processor(isApplicable, process) {
  return container => container.flatMap(value => {
    if (isApplicable(value))
      return ContainerIsDone(process(value));
    return Container(value);
  });
}
```

And your pipeline would be:

```
const { value, isDone } = processNoObject(...(Container(input)...);
...
```

Instead of spelling the pipeline out as nested function calls, we could use `Array#reduce()`:

```
const pipeline = [processObject, ..., processNoObject];
const { value, isDone } = pipeline.reduce((c, processor) => processor(c), Container(input));
```

Which means we don't necessarily need the `processor` constructor:

```
const pipeline = [
  [isObject, cloneObject],
  ...,
  [isNoObject, cloneNoObject],
];

let container = Container(input);
for (const [isApplicable, process] of pipeline) {
  container = container.flatMap(value => {
    if (isApplicable(value))
      return ContainerIsDone(process(value));
    return Container(value);
  });
}

const { value, isDone } = container;
if (isDone)
  return value;
throw new Error(...);
```

Which means we don't really need any of these containers and other abstractions *at all*:

```
const pipeline = [
  [isObject, cloneObject],
  ...,
  [isNoObject, cloneNoObject],
];

for (const [isApplicable, process] of pipeline) {
  if (isApplicable(input))
    return process(input);
}

throw new Error(...);
```

Which is of dubious value unless the pipeline will be configured dynamically. Probably, unrolling that loop to plain conditionals will be clearer:

```
if (isObject(input)) return cloneObject(input);
...
if (isNoObject(input)) return cloneNoObject(input);
throw new Error(...);
```

Even if SonarCube complains, such a simple implementation is much better for human understanding than introducing extra abstractions like hiding the actual control flow in your data structures. For this problem, functional programming is likely not a suitable answer since procedural programming is totally sufficient.

Comment: Don't reduce FP to monads. Your last statement is solely opinion-based (especially because you prefer imperative style according to your tags).

Comment: @ftor You're reading a lot into my tags, I'm actually quite fond of FP – when it solves a problem, instead of making code more complicated. Here, using higher-order functions or other techniques associated with FP seems to provide no value at all. A bit of simple code is better than more and more complicated code. I don't see how that view could be controversial.

Comment: @amon Sounds as if FP is just a little convenience tool, which you pull out of the drawer, whenever it solves a "problem". But it is rather a paradigm, fairly  incompatible with OO or imperative style.

Comment: I was also wondering if I shouldn't just make an exception to the SonarQube rule since a series of if statements is probably easier to understand. Then again, if you don't have to change the inner workings of the algorithm and just add new functionality, e.g. handle Set or something, it will probably be very easy, you just add another isSet and cloneSet, put it in the pipeline, and you're done.

Comment: @amon Minor nitpick - in the penultimate code snippet the `pipeline` is not the best variable name, because nothing is [passed from one element to another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(software)). On the other hand, I am not sure that such approach is `of dubious value unless the pipeline will be configured dynamically`. Quite the opposite - it is cleaner and less error-prone, while requiring basically zero additional effort over the `if`s , also it would be much easier to make building of this list dynamic in case it ever be required.

Comment: @amon Instead of just criticizing your answer, I have provided an alternative approach.

Comment: @PatrickHund Only you know which variant is better for your use case. Your current code is equally flexible as my suggested if–return statements since you'd need to edit the source code to insert the processor in the correct place either way. Putting callbacks into an array or into a type dict (see ftor's answer) is better if you want to register new clone cases at runtime, e.g. if this code is part of a framework and users can't edit this function (compare the Open/Closed principle). …

Comment: … Static analysis tools are a good smoke detector, but there are false positives. In particular, very simple switch/case style code is easier to understand for humans than the McCabe complexity (number of independent paths through the code) would suggest. Making exceptions is a valid reaction to such cases. After all, you can never eliminate complexity, only shuffle it around to make it more manageable. I think you've done very well that by extracting `isX()` and `cloneX()` functions for each supported type. How those functions are combined is just frosting on the cake.

Answer (score 1):

@amon's answer is quite good, and I generally would agree with the conclusion that in this case a simple sequence of if statements is clearest. However, I do think that your code hits on an important technique that I would associate with functional program, namely encoding the program's control flow in its data structures. At its most extreme, this looks like structuring your program as an interpreter over an ADT. We have a milder case here.

If we look at your `container` type, it is essentially `(Boolean, Object)`. Very frequently though, these sorts of products really want to be sum types and just don't have the language support. So I think a fair rendering (choosing Haskell as the target language) is something like

```
data Container a b = Done a | Ongoing b
```

The results of your processor function are of type

```
type Processor a b = Container a b -> Container a b
```

And defined by the following

```
processor :: (b -> Boolean) -> (b -> a) -> Processor a b
processor isApplicable f = \ container -> case container of 
    Done a    -> Done a
    Ongoing b -> if isApplicable a then Done (f b) else Ongoing b
```

Now we can see that the results of `processor` always have a fixed point at `Done a`. Indeed, part of our intention in calling it `Done` was to suggest that it represents the end of a computation. We can represent this suggestion by introducing a higher order function that reflects that.

```
mapContainer :: (b -> c) -> Container a b -> Container a c
mapContainer f (Done a) = Done a
mapContainer f (Ongoing b) = Ongoing (f b)
```

Typically we would call `mapContainer` `fmap` as `(Container a, mapContainer)` forms a functor as

```
mapContainer id == id
mapContainer (f . g) == mapContainer f . mapContainer g
```

So we would write

```
instance Functor (Container a) where
    fmap = mapContainer
```

Now we can rewrite `processor` to use `fmap`.

```
processor isApplicable f = \ container -> 
    case fmap (\b -> if isApplicable b then Done (f b) else Ongoing b) of
        Done a -> Done a
        Ongoing (Done a) -> Done a
        Ongoing (Ongoing b) -> Ongoing b
```

This actually looks a little worse, but we are getting close. The next step is to note that the bit in the middle represents another suggestion we want to express about `Container` objects, namely that when we hit `Done` anywhere in a stack we are done for good.

```
joinContainer :: Container a (Container a b) -> Container a b
joinContainer (Done a) = Done a
joinContainer (Ongoing (Done a)) = Done a
joinContainer (Ongoing (Ongoing b)) = Ongoing b
```

Now we can write `processor` as

```
processor isApplicable f = join . fmap (\b -> isApplicable b then Done (f b) else Ongoing b)
```

Now, those with some type-classes under their belt will recognize the similarity between `joinContainer` and [`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join). And once we realize that we have a `return` function in `Ongoing` we know we have enough to declare `Container` a monad.

```
instance Monad (Container a) where
    return = Ongoing
    c >>= f = joinContainer (mapContainer f c)
```

Now we can rewrite processor as

```
processor isApplicable f = \ c -> c >>= (\b -> if isApplicable b then Done (f b) else Ongoing b)
```

So we have found the monad at the core of your program. Now as @amon suggests, we can rewrite your `clone` function by essentially peeling out a bit of glue. Right now `clone` looks like

```
clone c = let c' = processor isNoObject cloneNoObject . processor isDate cloneDate . ... . processor isObject cloneObject $ return c
    in case c' of 
        Done a -> a
        Ongoing _ -> error ""
```

Which expanded out looks like

```
clone c = let c' = return c >>= (\b -> if isObject b then Done (cloneObject b) else Ongoing b) >>= ... >>= (\b -> if isNoObject b then Done (cloneNoObject b) else Ongoing b)
    in case c' of
        Done a -> a
        Ongoing _ -> error ""
```

Now things become a lot more manageable if we instead of factoring out the `>>= (\b -> ...)` part just factor out the `(\b -> ...)` part.

```
processor' isApplicable f b 
    | isApplicable b = Done (f b)
    | otherwise      = Ongoing b
```

Then we can write

```
clone c = let c' = (do
        object <- processor' isObject cloneObject c
        ...
        noObject <- processor' isNoObject cloneNoObject date
        return noObject)
    in case c' of 
        Done a -> a
        Ongoing _ -> error ""
```

And actually we can now recotnize `processor isX cloneX` as a Kleisi arrow and rewrite `clone` once more with [>=>](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-) (Kleisi arrow composition).

```
clone c = let c' = processor' isObject cloneObject >=> ... >=> processor' isNoObject cloneNoObject $ c
    in case c' of 
        Done a -> a
        Ongoing _ -> error ""
```

Now it may seem that all we have done is increased the obscurity of our code. In general though I think moving the branching logic of your program from the surface level into your data types and combinators benefits you in the long term by 1. enforcing a more algebraic thinking and 2. providing more rigidity in your control flows.

We could see algebraic thinking develop throughout this process as we discovered how we could express features of our program as features of our basic data structures; in this process we saw that the short-circuiting and the joining that was going on in our program naturally pushed us towards operations on our containers that embodied these. We also noticed that these operations fit into type abstractions, namely Functors and Monads.

It seems strange to think of more rigid control flows as a benefit in programming: surely flexibility is always a good thing? But constraints come with a plus side; modern languages phased out `goto` for a reason. In general I think of functional programming as a further advance along structural programming: instead of using our structured `if` and `while` constructs, we prefer to define types and higher order functions that represent more abstract control flows. When things are written this way, our code can become much easier to read and it becomes more difficult to introduce new complexities.

---

As a stray note: the `Container` type is much better known by its common name `Either` (`Either` is usually thought of as representing computations that can fail but it is more accurate to think of it as embodying short circuiting generally).

Comment: I would simply extend the native prototypes of all built-in `Object` types with correpsonding clone methods (not directly, but with a `WeakMap` as a type dictionary). Now a generic `clone` function just needs to look up the prototype of the given `Object` type  in the `WeakMap` in order to get the appropriate `clone` method. I guess this is called ad-hoc polymorphism. Wouldn't that be an alternative functional approach, completely without monads/sum types?

Comment: @ftor I like your solution, but I think it more reflects the dynamic-OO nature of JavaScript than any functional aspects. It's definitely better and way more idiomatic than the more pure-functional approach (mainly because "clone an arbitrary object" is a very non-purely-functional problem).

Comment: "_mainly because "clone an arbitrary object" is a very non-purely-functional problem_" - of course, now I understand it. Why should someone clone an immutable object? This issue doesn't occur in FP. Thanks!